# Concatenation of Consecutive Binary Numbers, Modulo Operation discussion behavior

Tags: java, data-structures, modulo

Here I am contributing the Java Solution for the problem.
Concatenation of Consecutive Binary Numbers:
Given an integer n, return the decimal value of the binary string formed by concatenating the binary representations of 1 to n in order, modulo 10^9 + 7.

```
class Solution {
    public int concatenatedBinary(int n) {
        long sum = 0;
    
        for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
            sum = ((sum << Integer.toBinaryString(i).length()) + i) % 1000000007;
        }
    
        return (int) sum;
    }
}
```

Now I have a doubt that is when we are modulating at each step within for loop. It will not impact the result till 1000000007 but after that, it will change the sum variable, and this cycle will repeat. Now, why doesn't this modulo impacting the overall result? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "Now, why doesn't this modulo impacting the overall result?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's take a simpler problem: Take the number 1000, write it as bits, then take the number 1001, write that as bits, concatenate the two, what's that, in decimal?

```
1000 in bits is 11 1110 1000
1001 in bits is 11 1110 1001
```

Thus, the answer'd be `1111 1010 0011 1110 1001`, or 1025001.

But, let's do a more mathy take on this: "concatenate the two" boils down to: "Shift the bits in the first number to the left to make enough room, then add the second number". And "shift left by X" is the same as 'multiply by 2<sup>X</sup>'. Just like if I have the number '1234', and I tell you to 'shift that left by 2 spots', it's the same as multiplying by 100: That turns it into 123400, which is 1234*100, and 100 is just 10<sup>2</sup>. So, 'shift left  by X spots' is the same as 'multiply by b<sup>X</sup>' where b is the 'base' of the number system we use; 2 in binary, 10 in decimal.

Thus, a different way to state the same result is: 'Take the number 1000, multiply it by 2<sup>10</sup>, add 1001 to it. Sure enough: `1000 * 2^10 + 1001` is indeed 1025001.

Thus, a single 'loop' in your algorithm is effectively: Take the result we have so far, multiply it by 2 a bunch of times (X times, where X is the position of the highest 1-bit in the number we're processing this loop), then add the new number.

So, it's just multiplication and addition.

Modulo has the property that it is stable for those operations.

Consider basic math: You were probably taught about the number line. A horizontal line, infinite in size.

A modulo system is no different, except the number line is a big loop. It's a circle. In modulo 1000000007 space, the numbers '5 and 6' are just as adjacent as the numbers '0 and 1000000006' are.

Given, on the normal number line, `a * b = c`, modulo has the property that this also means that `(a%Z * b%Z)%Z = c%Z` for any Z. The same goes for addition; if `a + b = c`, then `(a%Z + b%Z)%Z = c%Z` is also true. You can try a bunch of numbers and witness this, or try to prove this yourself, or search the web for proof of this property.

Example:

```
12 * 18 = 216
(12%7 * 18%7)%7 = 216%7
Yup, that checks out:
5 * 4 = 20
20%7 = 6.
216%7 is also 6.
```

Thus:

1. Your question boils down to a lot of applications of multiplying and addition.
2. multiply and add translate to modulo math without issue.
3. Therefore, your algorithm works.